# How to show Image from document directory inside Gallery App IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I am working in react native and I have downloaded some image from the internet inside the Document directory App folder in IOS. Now, I also want this image to show in IOS native Photos/Gallery App. Concern:

1. Do I need to make another copy of this image at some other folder to achieve it?
2. I have also found a method UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(), but I failed to understand the usage, Will it create another copy or I need to enable some magic flag kind of thing to work?

Comment: You have tagged Swift, Objective C and react native. Which are you using?

Comment: I am using react native and the react-native-image-crop-picker uses objective c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CameraRoll](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll) provides access to the local camera roll or photo library.

```
CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(tag, [type]);
```

Saves the photo or video to the camera roll or photo library.

On Android, the tag must be a local image or video URI, such as "file:///sdcard/img.png".

On iOS, the tag can be any image URI (including local, remote asset-library and base64 data URIs) or a local video file URI (remote or data URIs are not supported for saving video at this time).

**Note:**

Whenever save image to document directory also need to save that image to **CameraRoll / Photolibrary**

`React-native` `camera roll` extension to store photos in specific album

[react-native-store-photos-album](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-store-photos-album)

Comment: Can I create new Album in Photos app in IOS with this app?

Comment: you can save image to photoLibrary and get image from library (you can use filter with get photos) 
more information in react-native camera roll docs please check that

Comment: Also, I think, I don't need this Camera Roll for Android, if I store the images on external folder with in internal memory. Do I?

Comment: I don't think this Camera Roll helps in creating a new Album in react native

Comment: Yes you can't create album but you will get photo with filter

Comment: Any help on creating the album?

Comment: react-native-store-photos-album is working awesome. Thanks